# Continuity of CDF of a discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity, random-variables, step-function

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with $Range(X) \subset \mathbb{N}$. How to prove that the CDF is

a) not continuous at all points in the range of $X$.

b) differentiable at all other points.

Comment: when the CDF is viewed as a function from $\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$, the CDF is a step function, i.e. it has jump discontinuities at points in $Range(X)$, and is elsewhere constant (and hence differentiabile)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let $p_n = \mathbb{P}[X=n]$ and consider some $n$ with $p_n \ne 0$. The CDF is defined as
$$
F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \le x]
$$
so as you are approaching from the left would be
$$
F_X(n^-) = \mathbb{P}[X < n] = \mathbb{P}[X \le n-1]
$$
and when you approach from the right you get
$$
F_X(n^+) = \mathbb{P}[X \le n] = F_X(n^-) + p_n.
$$
Can you complete the problem now?

Comment: Yes. $F_{x} (n)$ has jump discontinuity for all $n$ such that $p_{n} \neq 0$. At all other points, it is  continuous. Thanks